# Date column value in date time index evaluation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

As you can see in my code image. I'm attempting to populate a new column with a value that is based on the date column. If the date value is within the date range, then it would give the new column the pertaining string value. I am not able to get a Boolean when comparing the datetime column value to the specified range. I'm basically diving a year would of transactional data into 6 periods, I then want to compare the rate of change between each period for each part number.
I want to make this with relative variables as the data may not always contain the same daily frequency.

```
date_rng[:2]
  DatetimeIndex(['2021-03-18 16:05:22.150133', '2021-01-04 08:04:17.720106400'], 
  dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
df['Date'][1]
  datetime.date(2021, 3, 17)
  (date_rng[:2])[:2]
   DatetimeIndex(['2021-03-18 16:05:22.150133', '2021-01-04 08:04:17.720106400'], 
   dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
 df['Date'][1] in (date_rng[:2])[:2]
   False'''##this should return True
```

[notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSvuJ.png)

Comment: Your `in` check is checking if that exact value is found in that **array-like** object, not whether that value exists between the bounds. You'd need an `Interval` object if you want to deal with being in between those two bounds with `in` (or just use something like `between`)

Comment: I tried between and inbetween with no success. I will look into making the Datetime index an Interval. I was hoping there was a comparison or syntax that would work with the datetimeindex. Thank you for the feedback!